# cant save model instance if I populate decimal field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model, decimal

So this happened to me:

```
thing = ModelClass()
thing.foo = bar()
thing.do_Stuff()
thing.save()  #works fine
thing.decimal_field = decimal_value
thing.save()  #error here
```

Traceback follows:

```
TypeError at /journey/collaborators/2/

unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'Decimal' and 'str'

274.             oH.save()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  460.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  543.                         for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py" in inner
  28.             return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_save
  787.                 self.max_digits, self.decimal_places)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py" in value_to_db_decimal
  705.         return util.format_number(value, max_digits, decimal_places)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in format_number
  145.         return u'%s' % str(value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".1") ** decimal_places, context=context))
```

I've tried setting `decimal_value` to a `decimal.Decimal` instance, a float, an int and a string. It seems I can't save my model instance unless I leave that field blank.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Could you paste the Exception being raised?

Comment: @j.koch: My bad. done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I changed:

```
 decimal_field = models.DecimalField(decimal_places='2',max_digits='6',null=True)
```

To

```
 decimal_field = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2,max_digits=6,null=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the stacktrace, it looks like `decimal_places` here

```
return u'%s' % str(value.quantize(decimal.Decimal(".1") ** decimal_places, context=context))
```

Is a `str` and you are attempting to do an operation (`pow`) that does not allow `Decimal` and `str` types

So you can try changing `decimal_places` to `int(decimal_places)` or figure out why it is a `str` and not an `int`.

Comment: It's failing on the call to `save`, I tried an int, a float, a string and a decimal all with the same result. It's all explained in the question

Comment: @Ngenator: I agree, you might want to look over the definition of the DecimalField in your Model. I was able to recreate this error by setting the decimal_places-attribute to a string instead of an int.

Comment: Technically the error is being raised on the last line, but I do see now that the the last line is in is a django module (I misread that when I answered). Perhaps your actual code would help then, since I don't see anything wrong with your pseudo code...